# Why does Firefox require a double click to edit Zoho spreadsheet?

Tags: firefox, zoho

I am using Zoho Spreadsheet, an alternative to Google Spreadsheets, that is an online browser based editor. The problem is when I use Firefox on this computer running Windows 10, it requires me to double click to open a link (in the spreadsheet).

When I use Firefox on other computers, I can single click a link and it opens.
When I use Microsoft Edge on this computer, I can single click a link and it opens.

So, I know this is a Firefox browser issue, I have tried the following:

- Clear browser cache, history, cookies, etc.
- Starting Firefox in Safe Mode
- Disable all addons
- Change to default theme
- Upgrading Firefox
- Using private mode
- Restore to default
- Refresh Firefox
- Restart computer
- Uninstall antivirus

However, I just can't get this to use single click.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was an issue with Firefox, which was fixed in a subsequent version of the browser.

Comment: I think it may be helpful for anyone who can hit the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by upgrading again to Firefox 49.x.